# Can I bring an empty eggshell into Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia

On Tuesday, I have a flight from Poland to Australia. I am migrating there, hence I want to take more than just clothes with me.

I have a hand-painted eggshell that is of great sentimental value to me. I know that I cannot bring food with me, but does it include eggshells as well? The shell is empty inside.

Comment: I'll offer this as a comment as I can't find the definitive AU source. I'm guessing you're referring to a pisanka. Biosecurity is very strict in Australia and eggs, in all forms are not allowed in. While the inside has been blown/sucked out before the shell was painted, and is now a decorative item, you may be required to have it irradiated, which does no harm to it. Make sure you mark yes on your incoming passenger card where asks about eggs, and a biosecurity officer will inspect it and determine whether it requires treatment or not.

Comment: @Dorothy That sounds like a great way to lose the item permanently with no recourse should said agent determine it ineligible for entry. Surely it is better to inquire in advance and bring associated appropriate paperwork if one must deal with a border agent.

Comment: @Eric Even after properly sending photographs, a history of the item and an explanation to a Border Force customer questions email address, there is still every chance that the Border Agent will confiscate it anyway, even if the email says you are fine. From memory, if rejected from a border check, you can usually pay to have it reshipped back to your country of origin (at cost), have it irradiated (also at cost) or destroyed (also at cost).

Comment: @Eric if my vast experience watching that Australian border show taught me anything, it is to always declare your goods, especially if you're unsure. The trouble if you don't is not worth it.

Comment: An egg from what species of bird?

Comment: I believe it is a goose egg.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[BICON](https://bicon.agriculture.gov.au/BiconWeb4.0/) is the official database for import conditions.  You should be able to search it to get exactly what you need.

For example, a search for *[egg shell ornaments](https://bicon.agriculture.gov.au/BiconWeb4.0/ImportConditions/Bookmark/GetBookmark?EvaluationStateId=7c518d13-fba3-4161-bec6-25f2cf5cf26d&EvaluationPhase=ImportDefinition&CaseElementPk=539556&ImportDefinitionPathwayNodePK=6&OnshoreManagementPathwayNodePK=)* gave me the following result:

> a. A Department of Agriculture and Water Resources import permit is not required.
>
> b. Conditions of Administration
>
> 1. Documents must be provided with each consignment which:
>
>    1.1. identify the consignment e.g. entry number
>
>    1.2. identify all goods being imported as part of this consignment e.g. invoice or waybill or importer’s manifest
>
>    1.3. describe the goods being imported (where not clear). Example 1: Product XRab = Purified protein derived from rabbits. Example 2: Product AX = Synthetic antibiotic. Example 3: Comte = Cheese.
> 2. For further information please contact:
>
>    Regional - Clearance assistance
>
>    Canberra - Administrative assistance or technical assistance: email  or phone 1800 900 090
>
> c. Professionally prepared undecorated and decorated blown eggs or egg shell ornaments/paintings may be imported without treatment provided the product is free from organic materials. Egg shell ornaments may be painted or lacquered.
>
> d. All egg ornaments and paintings are subject to inspection on arrival. Blown eggs that appear not to have been professionally prepared, or where the cleaning process is unknown, may not be imported unless treated by one of the following methods:
>
> 1. Washing the outside and inside of the shell with 2% sodium hypochlorite for a minimum of 10 minutes, or
> 2. 1% Virkon or 1% Virucidal X, or
> 3. Gamma irradiation at 50 kGray.
>
>    Consignments that do not meet the above conditions must be exported or disposed of.

Comment: I'm confused: someone downvoted this answer and then tried to edit out the links to the source of this info, accusing them of being "spam". But they're links to the relevant part of the Australian Government website! Perhaps the user who did this could explain?

Comment: @user568458 I can't see any edits that were approved but I definitely agree the links are ***NOT*** spam. Maybe someone was having an off day?

Comment: +1, but please summarize the answer as "yes, you can import them", since that's what condition C boils down to.

Comment: Due to a tight margin of time I decided not to bring it with me. I was actually in flight when this answer was given. Thanks anyways, though.